# Delphi XE2 TCPServer execute procedure on midnight

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcpserver

Does anyone have ide or tips on how to execute a specific procedure at midnight on TCPServer? I'm a beginner on Delphi and have no idea how to do it.

Problem is that I can't execute my procedure when I receive data it takes too long get info from a database and insert into the file and other program uses that info on opening.

Comment: Add a thread to the server, and in its execute method, periodically check if it is time to do the long running operation. The TCP server by itself is not able to trigger actions periodically.

Comment: Maybe, it makes sense to write an utility which will perform desired actions and start it with windows sheduler / cron.

Comment: 1) Option one -- as mentioned below -- use Task Schedule 2) Option two -- once your application is started, calculated time difference between NOW and MIDNIGHT. Set it as duration in TTimer....